# highcharts with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json, highcharts

i m try to implement highcharts on my website but i dont know how i can get info from database on exactly away.

On my jquery i have this

```
    xAxis: {
                categories: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
            },
```

this represent the days of the current month, like today is 10 so go 1 to 10

```
series: [{
                name: 'acessos',
                data: [1,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,4]
            },
```

this represent the clicks by day

so my database have this structure

```
tabstats |tabstats.Stats_Id | tabstats.Stats_Type | tabstats.Stats_Clicks | tabstats.Stats_Date |
```

so them i have

```
Stats_Id = 1 / Stats_Type = 1 / Stats_Clicks = 10 / Stats_Date = 2012-05-01

Stats_Id = 2 / Stats_Type = 1 / Stats_Clicks = 5 / Stats_Date = 2012-05-02
```

etc for each day

so i m try to first get the current days of the month

and the clicks for each day.

Thanks for any help.

i figured how to output the days of the current month like this

```
for($i=1; $i <= date("d"); $i++) { $days[] = $i;    }
echo json_encode($days); // ouput [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Now i just need to fix about the clicks

```
for($i=1;$i <= date("d"); $i++) {
        $Sql = "SELECT COUNT(Stats_Clicks) AS Total FROM tabstats WHERE DAY(Stats_Date) = $i
                AND MONTH(Stats_Date) = $month
                AND YEAR(Stats_Date) = $year 
                ";
        $Query = mysql_query($Sql,$Conn) or die (mysql_error($Conn));
        $Rs = mysql_fetch_array($Query);    

        $clicks[] = $Rs['Total'];
    }
    echo json_encode($clicks);
```

but here i got a problem, the json output returns this

```
["1","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]
```

but i need without quotes, i tried using a simple vector but dint works for me.

I dont know if my code is the best solution or correctly but this is the only away i m going to the result i need.

thanks.

Comment: is Stats_Date a mysql Date Field?

Comment: Yes (Y-m-d), i used just date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

```
$clicks[] = (int)$Rs['Estatistica_Click'];
```

fixed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this too

```
echo json_encode($clicks,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```